# How to compare contents of 64 byte array with long, in java?

Tags: java

I have a byte array of 64 in size. I am receiving 64 bytes of data from `UsbConnection.bulkTRansfer()`. I want to check whether I received "Sync" packet or not. "Sync" is a long constant with value `4006390527l`. Here's my code.

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
bytesReceived += usbConnection.bulkTransfer(usbEndpointIn, buffer, 64, 2000);

String l=Base64.encodeToString(buffer,0);
long ll=Long.parseLong(l);

if(C.SYNC_PAD_TO_HOST == ll) {
 Log.d(TAG,"SyncReceived");//This is the Sync
 gotSync=true;
 System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, rcvbuf, 0, buffer.length);
}
```

I am getting very weird results. Never does the if condition becomes true. Whats wrong here.

Comment: `Sync` sounds more like a 64 **BIT** value...

Comment: 64 bytes is much more than can fit in a `long`. Please tell us what those 64 bytes are.

Comment: I'll try to guess...Are you trying to read 64 bytes and you got a *Sync* if the first byte is `0xEECCAAFF` ?

Comment: I'm afraid your code makes no sense.  Doing encodeToString converts the received data to gibberish.  parseLong will not make heads or tails of it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here.  A USB-Sync for full-speed is 32-bits.  An `int` is capable of containing the data, but not as an unsigned integer.  The only reason your code stores it as a `long` is to store values of `0x80000000` to `0xFFFFFFFF` as a positive number.  However, only the least significant 32-bits of the `long` are used.

To calculate the first little-endian unsigned 32-bit number in the stream and store it as a `long`, use:

```
long ll = (buffer[0] & 0xFF)
        | ((buffer[1] & 0xFF) << 8)
        | ((buffer[2] & 0xFF) << 16)
        | ((buffer[3] & 0xFFL) << 24);
```

Here's a breakdown of what's happening:

Your Sync packet in hex is `0x17E1444C`.  USB transmits this value using little-endian, which means the least significant byte is sent first.  Over the wire, the bytes come in this order:

4C 44 E1 17

To break-down the steps:

```
long ll = buffer[0] & 0xFF;
// ll == 0x4C & 0x000000FF
//    == (long) 0x0000004C
//    == 0x000000000000004C

ll |= (buffer[1] && 0xFF) << 8;
// ll == 0x000000000000004C | ((0x44 & 0x000000FF) << 8)
//    == 0x000000000000004C | (0x00000044 << 8)
//    == 0x000000000000004C | 0x00004400
//    == 0x000000000000004C | (long) 0x00004400
//    == 0x000000000000004C | 0x0000000000004400
//    == 0x000000000000004C

ll |= (buffer[2] & 0xFF) << 16;
// ll == 0x000000000000444C | ((0xE1 & 0x000000FF) << 16)
//    == 0x000000000000444C | (0x000000E1 << 16)
//    == 0x000000000000444C | 0x00E10000
//    == 0x000000000000444C | (long) 0x00E10000
//    == 0x000000000000444C | 0x0000000000E10000
//    == 0x0000000000E1444C
```

That last inclusion illustrates why we use `& 0xFF`.  Without using this bitwise AND, here's what happens without using `& 0xFF`:

```
ll |= buffer[2] << 16;
// ll == 0x000000000000444C | ((int) 0xE1) << 16)
//    == 0x000000000000444C | (0xFFFFFFE1 << 16)
//    == 0x000000000000444C | 0xFFE10000
//    == 0x000000000000444C | (long) 0xFFE10000
//    == 0x000000000000444C | 0xFFFFFFFFFFE10000
//    == 0xFFFFFFFFFFE1444C
```

This is because `E1` exceeds the maximum positive `byte` (`0x7F`), so it's treated as a negative number.  When cast directly to `int`, the negative sign is maintained.  To avoid this behaviour, we cast it to `int` by using a full 8-bit AND.

Now back to the process.  The last byte:

```
ll |= (buffer[3] & 0xFFL) << 24;
// ll == 0x0000000000E1444C | ((0x17 & 0x00000000000000FF) << 24)
//    == 0x0000000000E1444C | (0x0000000000000017 << 24)
//    == 0x0000000000E1444C | 0x0000000017000000
//    == 0x0000000017E1444C
```

You'll notice the last bitwise AND performed above is using a `long` version of `0xFF`.  This is because a left-shift of 24 bits (or higher) has the potential of making a negative `int` if the least significant byte exceeds the maximum positive byte (`0x7F`).  Imagine instead of `17` that the last byte is `A7`.  Here's what happens when using using `& 0xFF` instead of `& 0xFFL`:

```
ll |= (buffer[3] & 0xFF) << 24;
// ll == 0x0000000000E1444C | ((0xA7 & 0x000000FF) << 24)
//    == 0x0000000000E1444C | (0x000000A7 << 24)
//    == 0x0000000000E1444C | 0xA7000000
//    == 0x0000000000E1444C | (long) 0xA7000000
//    == 0x0000000000E1444C | 0xFFFFFFA7000000
//    == 0xFFFFFFFFA7E1444C
```